# Does Hbase memstore and in-memory are same?

Tags: get, hbase

Why is data not immediately flushing to file system ?
 By default how long will data  be available in memstore before flushing to file-system?
for each write data will be store in memstore like per each read also data will write to memstore/

Answer (score 0):

Flushing is nothing but RPC to store into region server,
Data can be flushed to Region server by

1. `put` operation on table, The Row/s will be transfered to Region server.
2. if we set Buffer size by `setWriteBufferSize()`, Then when buffer become full.
3. or by calling `flushCommits()` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Memstore acts as a in-memory cache of the last written data and also ensures that when written to HDFS as a HFile, all the row keys are primarily sorted. Hence, before flushing , the rows are sorted and then flushed.  This is primarily because files in HDFS cannot be modified once written .
  Tune the following two for Memstore flushes

```
 hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size
 hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.lowerLimit
```

Frequent Memstore flushes can also degrade the performance of read operations has HBase has to look into tons of HFiles that are caused by frequent flushes.

Hope this helps.